SQL - How to select a table name and use that in your SQL
in my database I have tables which have incrementing numbers after a word, I would like to find the MAX table name and use that in another SELECT in the same script. I plan to run this script through Ingres Terminal Manager (ITM).
I can find my max table name with:
SELECT MAX(table_name)
FROM iitables
WHERE table_name LIKE 'job1_%';

My other simple SQL would be:
SELECT id
FROM job1_123456
WHERE type = '1';

My question is, how can I combine these so the second SQLs FROM clause uses the MAX job1 from the initial SQL?
Many thanks in advance, and if anymore information is needed just let me know.

If you want to combine these two then you will have to use dynamic sql. I don't think its possible with static sql. How are you executing the sqls e.g shell, program ?

Hi, thank you. I am using Ingres Terminal Monitor (ITM).

try:
SET @max_table_name = (SELECT MAX(table_name)
                       FROM iitables
                       WHERE table_name LIKE 'job1_%');

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id FROM ', @max_table_name, ' WHERE type = ''1''');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

